# Can my parents legally prevent me from working at 15 in Utah?

Tags: workplace, utah

Can my parents legally prevent me from going to work at 15 in Utah when I already have a job?
My parents refuse to let me go to work even with good behavior and all A's in school.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Subject to laws on child welfare, parents have complete authority on what their children can and can’t do until they are no longer children at 18.

So, yes, they can prohibit you from having a job.